# XAMPP on windows 10 is not running php

Tags: php, jquery, html

Project structure is as follows

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\Documentation
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\css
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\images
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\js
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\videos
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\404.html
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\contact.php
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\HTML\index.html
C:\xampp\htdocs\myProject\PSD
```

I have a contact form in index.html that is controlled by a javascript file. This code stops default form submit, performs error checks and then uses ajax to make a post request to contact.php. The javascript code runs, it detects the php (see the alert in the code below just after the axjax funtion call. The value of d is the php script in the alert, but none of the debug lines in the php code get called and it never returns 'success'.

Here is the form

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="phpcontactform">
      <div class="control-group">
        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <input class="input-block-level" type="email" placeholder="Email ID" name="email" id="email">
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <input class="input-block-level" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" name="mobile" id="mobile">
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <textarea class="input-block-level" rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Your Message" id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="control-group">
        <p>
          <input class="btn btn-danger btn-large" type="submit" value="Send Message">
        </p>
        <span class="loading"></span> </div>
    </form>
```

here is the javascript

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phpcontactform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name");
        var email = $("#email");
        var mobile = $("#mobile");
        var msg = $("#message");
        var flag = false;
        if (name.val() == "") {
            name.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
            name.focus();
            flag = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            name.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        } if (email.val() == "") {
            email.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
            email.focus();
            flag = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            email.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
        } if (msg.val() == "") {
            msg.closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
            msg.focus();
            flag = false;
            return false;
        } else {
            msg.closest(".control-group").removeClass("error").addClass("success");
            flag = true;
        }
        var dataString = "name=" + name.val() + "&email=" + email.val() + "&mobile=" + mobile.val() + "&msg=" + msg.val();
        $(".loading").fadeIn("slow").html("Loading...");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            url: "http://localhost/myProject/HTML/contact.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function (d) {
                alert("d: "+d);
                $(".control-group").removeClass("success");
                if(d == 'success') // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                    $('.loading').fadeIn('slow').html('<font color="green">Mail sent Successfully.</font>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
                else
                    $('.loading').fadeIn('slow').html('<font color="red">Mail not sent.</font>').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $(".control-group").removeClass("success").removeClass("error");
    });
})
```

And finally here is the php

```
<?php
echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects:' );</script>";

$name  = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email = $_REQUEST["email"];
$mobile   = $_REQUEST["mobile"];
$msg   = $_REQUEST["msg"];

echo "<script>";
echo "alert('this also works');";
echo "</script>";

$to    = "myemail@gmail.com";
if (isset($email) && isset($name) && isset($msg)) {
    $subject = $name."sent you a message via Raaga";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n" ;
    $msg   = "From: ".$name."<br/> Email: ".$email ."<br/> Mobile: ".$mobile." <br/>Message: ".$msg;

    echo "<script>alert('this maybe works');</script>";

   $mail =  mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
  if($mail)
    {
        echo 'success';
    }

else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('name:'+$name);</script>";
        echo 'failed';
    }
}

echo "<script>alert('this finally works');</script>";

?>
```

I tried moving contact.php to the htdocs root but that didnt work. Have turned off all antivirus and firewalls but that didnt work either. Am at a loss. Thought php was supposed to work out of the box with xampp?

Comment: Have you started the Apache webserver using the XAMPP control panel? Also; you might have some trouble sending emails using XAMPP, because you need to configure the mail server correctly.

Comment: Yes I started Apache using the control panel. Should I start it another way? Do you have some links to some documentation on how to configure the mail server? I had xampp running on an old windows 10 machine before and never had any issues like this.

Comment: "it never returns 'success'" is not an indication that PHP isn't working at all. Your PHP script has the potential to return several other outputs. What **does** it return, instead?

Comment: It doesn't run the echo lines either though. Those alerts should display if the code is running no? When I try to grab the value of d and print to the console nothing shows

Comment: No. Echoing `<script>` blocks in a PHP script which is intended to be called by AJAX makes no sense, because anything you echo is considered as the response data. And the response data is delivered to the `d` variable in your receiving JavaScript. It is not interpreted as executable code. So if you want to output something to the client, then just echo the raw text, not JS code. The JavaScript which deals with receiving the response can decide how to output it on the screen. But if you just want to add some debugging logs, maybe log them to a file on the server instead.

Comment: Thank you. I'm a php noob. I did try writing to a file also but that didnt work. But okay, maybe the issue isn't that php isnt working then

Comment: "When I try to grab the value of d and print to the console nothing shows"...nothing at all? It's just blank? That's a little more concerning. Have you got error reporting / logging switched on in PHP? What is the HTTP status code returned by the server (you can see it in your browser's Network tools)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205997/discussion-between-philip-butler-and-adyson).

Comment: You need to include your contact.php file inside your form file.

Comment: Why would I need to do that? External php files are a thing?

Comment: Found the problem. Just include <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> in your form and you can have your working form. It's working for me.

Comment: what? no that isnt the issue at all

Comment: Sorry those lines are included in the index.html. The issue is that the mail server was not correctly configured in xampp. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so thanks to ADyson for the help. The issue was not that php isn't running, its that the mail server was not properly configured.